# Adding & Removing string components in a tibble

Tags: r

I have a tibble of stock name:

```
 A tibble: 239 x 3
   symbole     entreprise                secteur              
   <chr>       <chr>                     <chr>                
 1 TSX : AAV   Advantage Oil & Gas       Énergie              
 2 TSX : ABX   Barrick Gold              Matériaux            
 3 TSX : ACM.A Astral Media              Consommation Cyclique
 4 TSX : ACO.X Atco                      Utilitaires          
 5 TSX : AEM   Agnico-Eagle              Matériaux            
 6 TSX : AGF.B La Société de Gestion AGF Finance              
 7 TSX : AGI   Alamos Gold               Matériaux            
 8 TSX : AGU   Agrium                    Matériaux            
 9 TSX : AIM   Aimia                     Consommation Cyclique
10 TSX : ALA   AltaGas                   Énergie              
# ... with 229 more rows
```

I want to remove the "TSX:" part in the column name, add ".TO" to each name and replace the "." in some names by "-" .

So that the name "TSE:ACO.X" becomes "ACO-X.TO" .....etc....etc....

I tried several solution and the only thing I get is a column full of dot!

Comment: Show exactly what you tried so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a series of gsub/pastes, first removing the TSX:, then replacing the periods, then appending .TO. Because of the way mutate works, we can put them all as a series of tag=value statements inside one mutate:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(symbole=gsub("TSX \\: ","",symbole), 
  symbole=gsub("\\.","-",symbole),
  symbole=paste0(symbole,".TO"))
```

Comment: That method add the "-" and the ".TO" but does not remove the "TSX :" in front of the stock names.

Comment: Works on my side... Can you give me the output just for `as.vector(df$symbole)'?

Comment: or better yet, add the `dput(df)` to your original question.

Comment: I tried using str_remove and str_replace.  If I try to remove TSX, it also remove the X in some names.....and I don't whant that!

Comment: as.vector(tsx$symbole) gives me a vector of names:  [1] "TSX : AAV" etc...

Comment: If I use mutate(symbole=gsub("[TSX : ]", "", symbole) in the first line it takes out all "TSX : " but also some X in some names like ACO.X becomes ACO-.TO

Comment: I finally had another line to the solution:  symbole=gsub("\\:", "", symbole)